# How can I make octave not catch sigsegv?

Tags: segmentation-fault, octave, core-file

In other words, when octave crashes, I want to produce a real corefile , not an octave-core.  By default, octave catches the signal and produces an octave-core.  However, because my segfault is happening deep within external libraries, the octave-core isn't particularly helpful. I'm hoping there is a way to produce a real core without having to actively change the octave source code.

Comment: Is this for an extension you added, that you are trying to debug?

Comment: @Jmoney38 Yes, though I believe the problem is ultimately in a 3rd party library I am using.  It's a bit hard to explain the circumstances of the crashes.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your extension with GDB, and then debugging octave with GDB? That could shed some more light on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About 10 years ago, this discussion was held here [At nabble](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Signal-handling-td1615083.html). At the time the conclusion was exactly what you said: in order to change the way that the interrupts and signals are handled you would have to do a fundamental rewrite of some of the core elements of Octave.

It looks like a year later the same question was raised, and someone had put in actual effort into rewriting Octave's [signal handling](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/signal-handling-td1643051.html). I have had the same question, as I enjoy in my C/C++ rewriting how signals are handled to clean up before my programs exit, examine on crash errors more closly etc. However it appears that Octave still doesn't do a very good job with this yet. I have found a few more discussions others have had about signal handling in the last year or so, but nothing that would provide a simple interface such as the one you are asking for.